# Displaying of different prompt message in different screen resolutions using html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Ex: On click of button,  In desktop version screens it should display prompt message as ' Hi'.
.      same on click in mobile screen sizes it should display prompt message as "Hello".

Comment: you can use modal of bootstrap. It's responsive for all kinds of screen.

Comment: What you have tried before. show some code as well.

Comment: <div class="alert">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  This is an alert box.
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  if (width > 480 && height > 800) {
    alert('hi');
  } else {
    alert('hello');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28241682/4857206) answer out. Then after getting the width of your screen you can

`getElementById("my_element").innerHTML()` and set whatever you want to.